# Return type is not identical to nor covariant with return type "MediaDevice*" of overridden virtual function "MediaFactory :: FMediaDevice"

Tags: c++, factory, abstract

I have following abstract factory:

```
#include  "MediaDevice.h"

class MediaFactory {
public:
    MediaFactory();
    virtual ~MediaFactory();
    virtual  MediaDevice * FMediaDevice (int type) = 0;
};
```

and following factory which inherits from abstract facotry:

```
#include "MediaFactory.h"
class JVCMedDevFactory : public MediaFactory {
public:
    MediaDevice* FMediaDevice (int type) {
        switch ((type_e)type) {
            case CDPlayer_e:
            return new JVCCdPlayer() ;
            case DVDPlayer_e:
                return new JVCVcrPlayer() ;
        }
} 
};
```

Media device is :

```
#include <string>
#include <utility>
using namespace std;
class MediaDevice {
 public:
MediaDevice();
    virtual ~MediaDevice();
virtual void Start () = 0 ;
virtual void Stop () = 0 ;
    virtual void Forward () = 0 ;
virtual void Rewind () = 0 ;
virtual pair <string,string> getName () const = 0;
protected:
pair <string,string> DeviceName;
};
```

This is how I define JVC players:

```
#include "MediaDevice.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;   
class JVCCdPlayer : public MediaDevice {
public:
    JVCCdPlayer(){
            DeviceName.first = "JVC";
            DeviceName.second = "CD";
    }
    void Start (){
    cout << "Playing " << this->getName().first << "," << this->getName().second <<     endl;
}
    void Stop (){
    cout << "Stopped " << this->getName().first << "," << this->getName().second     <<endl;
    }
    void Forward (){
    cout << "Rewind " << this->getName().first << "," << this->getName().second <<endl;
}
void     Rewind (){
    cout << "Forward " << this->getName().first << "," <<this->getName().second <<endl;
    }
    pair <string,string> getName () const{
    return DeviceName;
    }
    ~JVCCdPlayer(){}
   };
```

And I get the following error

Return type is not identical to nor covariant with return type "MediaDevice*" of overridden virtual function  "MediaFactory :: FMediaDevice"

It is importnat that in visula studio i have red line under FMediaDevice in the declaration MediaDevice* FMediaDevice (int type) { in class MedDevFactory. And it doesn't matter what i return. I can return 0 and still get the error.

Why?

Comment: We need to see the definitions of `JVCCdPlayer` and `JVCVcrPlayer`.

Comment: The error seems to indicate that `MediaDevice` is resolving to two different types between the definition of `MediaFactory` and `JVCMedDevFactory`. Are you using forward declarations in namespaces or something that might cause this to happen?

Comment: I've added declarations of JVCCdPlayer and JVCVcrPlayer

Comment: @sera:  Post also the content of `"MediaDevice.h"`

Comment: @Nawaz: It is already there. Under "Media device is:". Thanks!

Comment: @sera: see the edit in my post.

Comment: Voting to close as the problem was solved "off line" with information not available to all viewers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the error message, it seems like either `JVCCdPlayer` or `JVCVcrPlayer` (or both) is not derived from `MediaDevice`. Is that so?

You've to derive both from `MediaDevice`. Make sure your definitions look like this:

```
class JVCCdPlayer : public MediaDevice
{
};

class JVCVcrPlayer : public MediaDevice
{
};
```

Or somewhere in the hierarchy, `MediaDevice` should be present.

---

The class `MediaDevice` has member data `DeviceName` which is of type `pair<string,string>`, but you've not included the header in which `pair` is defined. So include `<utility>`. Similarly, make sure you've included all the necessary headers.

Also, I wouldn't write `using namespace std` in a header file. So I would re-write `MediaDevice.h` as :

```
#ifndef MEDIA_DEVICE_H
#define MEDIA_DEVICE_H

#include <string>
#include <utility>

class MediaDevice 
{
  public:
     MediaDevice();
     virtual ~MediaDevice();
     virtual void Start () = 0 ;
     virtual void Stop () = 0 ;
     virtual void Forward () = 0 ;
     virtual void Rewind () = 0 ;
     virtual std::pair<std::string,std::string> getName () const = 0;
  private:
     std::pair<std::string,std::string> DeviceName;
};

#endif
```

That is, I would qualify each name with `std::` instead of `using namespace std`.

By the way, I don't see the definition of the following pure virtual function:

```
virtual pair <string,string> getName () const = 0;
```

Have you defined it in the derived classes? (although the error doesn't say that this is the problem, but still make sure this as well).

Besides, the member data `DeviceName` is declared as `private` which needs to be `protected` because you're accessing it from the derived classes `JVCVcrPlayer` and `JVCCdPlayer`  .

Comment: From visual studio I can see that the problem is with declaration of the function  MediaDevice* FMediaDevice (int type). It marks with red line FMediaDevice. And it doesn't matter for him what i return. I put retrun 0 and still saw the error. But JVCCDPlayer and JVCVcrPlayer are derrived from MediaDevice also.

What does it mean "MediaDevice should be present." ?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: @sera: why `pair` doesn't require header? Also,  my guess is that your program gives other error. Did you posted all error messages?

Comment: @Nawaz: I guess already included headers implicitly include `<utility>` in Visual Studio.

Comment: @Nawaz : I'm sorry. I've checked now and indeed saw another error: It marked with red line under - return new JVCCdPlayer() ; - and said that object of abstract class type JVCCdPlayer is not allowed. I suppose this happened because i changed today JvcCdPlayer and JVCVcrPlayer classes and removed from them implementation of pure virtual functions.
But still even if i don't use this classes. Only return 0 instead. The first error i mentioned is still there. 
I used only 
#include <string>
using namespace std;
headers for pair

Comment: @sera: YES. I was right. That is because you've not defined `getName` pure virtual function in the derived classes. Always remember, pure virtual functions needs to be implemented in the derived classes!

Comment: @Nawaz : I returned implementation of pure virtual functions to class JVCCdPlayer. This removed the new error. But I still get the first error. :-(((((

Comment: @sera: I didn't get you. Can you send me your code so that I can see all the files and definitions myself, and tell you the problem?

Comment: @Nawaz: where can i get you email? Thanks!

Comment: @Nawaz: Thank you. I've sent the project to your email.

Comment: @sera: alright, got it. now let me see whats wrong with it. will reply back once I found the problem.

Comment: @sera: where are you? you should come online at gmail.

Comment: @Nawaz, @sera: Although this answer is marked as accepted I still can't see how the "not identical and not covariant" error was solved. What was the real problem?

Comment: @Charles: Actually, there were too many problems, so I asked him to  send me the code, I solved that offline. He was not able to reproduce the error here.

Comment: @Nawaz: I am still curious as to the underlying problem. I had a couple of suspicions. In any case this question should be closed as it's clearly not answerable from the information posted.

Comment: @Charles: Lots of problem: 1) he didn't define `main()`; 2) there were no guards in the headers, due to which redefinition errors were there;  3) he didn't define the constructor and destructor in the interface; 4) he declared `DeviceName` in the private section, yet was accessing it from the derived classes. Things like this

Answer (score 0):

MediaDevice is probably not a parent of JVCCdPlayer or JVCVcrPlayer.

Also note that the function JVCMedDevFactory::FMediaDevice is not always guaranteed to return a value - you should have a default case in the switch statement or a default return at the bottom of the function.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you help,
As i said, i tried to leave only one line - return 0 in implementation of function JVCMedDevFactory::FMediaDevice and still remained with error

Answer (score 0):

After the following changes, Visual Studio 2010 compiled your code (though I put it all in a single source file).

1. Including all required headers;
2. Making `MediaDevice::DeviceName` a protected (not private) member, so that it can be accessed by constructors of player classes;
3. Defining `type_e` as an enumeration;
4. Removing "pure virtual" `=0` specifier from declarations of `MediaDevice` member functions, and adding an obvious definition for `MediaDevice::getName().

In real code, the last step should instead add overriding definitions of pure virtual functions into player classes, but I was lazy to write it.

I need to say that at no stage I saw the "Return type is not identical to nor covariant with" diagnostics.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I suppose I have problem with "including all required headers". Can you show how you put the headers? Thanks

Comment: @sera: I needed to add `#include <iostream>` for `std::cout`, and I also added `#include <utility>` for `std::pair`, even though it is implicitly included through some other VC header.

Comment: Thank you for help. I followed the instructions of Nawaz and it solved the problem. But I believe that your solution was also good.